# How do I add/update a property inside an MSI from the command-line?

Tags: windows, command-line, installation, windows-installer, properties

I have an MSI installer in which I need to add or modify a short text property from the command-line.

This has to be done after the installer is built; I cannot modify the process that produces the installer in the first place.  It also has to be executed headless from a script.

When I say "property," it could be an MSI property, a value that gets written to the registery at install-time, or any other mechanism that can get this short custom text into the installed application when it runs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example VBScript that you could use to update (or add) a property post-build...

```vb
    Option Explicit

    Const MSI_FILE = "myfile.msi"


    Dim installer, database, view

    Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
    Set database = installer.OpenDatabase (MSI_FILE, 1)

    ' Update
    Set view = database.OpenView ("UPDATE Property SET Value = '" & myproperty & "' WHERE Property = 'MYPROPERTY'")

    ' .. or Add (Insert)
    Set view = database.OpenView ("INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) VALUES ('MYPROPERTY', '" & myproperty & "')")
    view.Execute
    database.Commit

    Set database = Nothing
    Set installer = Nothing
    Set view = Nothing
```

For more information check out the Windows Installer SDK (part of the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en))

There's a bunch of example scripts that you can use from the command line to do various MSI manipulation tasks

For example `WiRunSQL.vbs` lets you execute arbitrary SQL against an MSI.

Comment: Don't forget to update the package code in the Summary Information Stream when you change the package. While changing a property value is unlikely to cause actual problems even if you release multiple .msi files with different values, it's still something you need to do.

Comment: I've only found that I need to update the Summary Information when creating transforms, any reason why you need to update for all changes?

Comment: I can't even update a variable with this script and get a runtime error "Variable is undefined". I have checked in Orca the property is defined.

Comment: I know this is old but modified to add database.Commit.

Comment: I realize this post is a few years old. However, I stumbled onto this post while researching this very topic, learning shortly afterward that VBScript is currently in the process of being deprecated. That being said, for anyone else who may be looking for a solution, in the future, I suggest checking-out the following post, containing the same solution, converted to PowerShell. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152502/2649063

Answer (score 5):

```
c:\> msiexec /i yourmsi.msi THEPROPERTYNAME=valueofproperty
```

For more information type msiexec at the commandline.

EDIT: or change the .msi file itself by using sql statements and updating the property in the properties table:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372021(VS.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368568(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I thought that INSTALLS with a new property.  I don't want to install, I need to MODIFY the MSI file.

Comment: I don't think this deserved the downvote, as this fit the criteria specified by OP's question. Post-build, is an MSI property, and is certainly "any other mechanism that can get this short custom text into the installed application when it runs." It's not altering the MSI itself, but doing this at the installer's runtime is effectively the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is to add to @saschabeaumont 's answer in '09. Currently using dotNet 4.0

```
Option Explicit

Const MSI_FILE = "myFilePath.msi"
Const PROPERTY_STRING_Value = "FooBar"

Dim installer, database, view

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set database = installer.OpenDatabase (MSI_FILE, 1)

' Update
Set view = database.OpenView ("UPDATE Property SET Value = '" & PROPERTY_STRING_Value & "' WHERE Property = 'MYPROPERTY'")

' .. or Add (Insert)
Set view = database.OpenView ("INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) VALUES ('MYPROPERTY', '" & PROPERTY_STRING_Value & "')")

view.Execute()
database.Commit()

Set database = Nothing
Set installer = Nothing
Set view = Nothing
```

Comment: somehow latest one posted by @asarenski worked but previous one by saschabeaumont made no change in msi. +1

Comment: That is because @saschabeaumont forgot to add `database.Commit()`