# Edit MSI property table

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer

I have a two part question about editing an MSI with VBScript.

1. The below code will work with a static value (C:\users\x etc) to place into the MSI 'Property' table.  However, if I use a predefined variable then it inserts the variable name as text into the MSI and not what that variable translated to.  How do I get the `msi.OpenView` function to accept a variable for the value?

   The variable is created from a commandline argument.

   ```
   strNewServerName = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

   Set record = msiInstaller.CreateRecord(1)
   Set view = msi.OpenView("INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('SERVERNAME', 'strNewServerName')")

   view.Execute record
   ```
2. The `view.Execute` will error unless the property/row in the MSI is empty.  I have to take out all the fields I'm updating in the source MSI before I commit the new one for this to function.  Is there a way of triggering the `msi.OpenView("INSERT INTO...")` with an overwrite command for whatever is already in the row/table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are to ways to interpolate a variable's content into a string: concatenation and replacement. As in:

```
>> v = "content"
>> WScript.Echo "pipapo '" & v & "' popapi"
>> WScript.Echo Replace("pipapo '@' popapi", "@", v)
>>
pipapo 'content' popapi
pipapo 'content' popapi
>>
```

To change an existing record, use "Update" as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610269/603855).

Comment: Thanks, ok the Update function makes sense.

Not quite sure how you mean the replacement of text will work.  Whatever is written into the second set of quotes in  - VALUES ('SERVERNAME', 'strNewServerName')") - gets written as clear text with all logic stripped.

Comment: Ended up finding a way to do this similar to what you'd described but I couldn't quite make sense of yours.
set view = msi.OpenView("INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('SERVERPORT', '" & strNewServerPort & "')")